# Find PMF of $X^2$ if $X$~Dunif

Tags: probability

> (a) Find the distribution of $X^2$ for X ⇠ DUnif(0, 1,...,n).
>
> (b) Find the distribution of $X^2$for X ⇠ DUnif(−n, −n + 1,..., 0, 1,...,n).

I know how to do it in case of contionus r.v. Can you describe the general approach in case of discrete on these examples?

I think in this direction:

a) $P(Y=X^2)=\sum_{y=x^2}P(X=x)= P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=4)+P(X=9)...+P(X=n^2)= 1? $ $X \in (0, 1,...,n^2)$

b) $P(Y=X^2)=\sum_{y=x^2}P(X=x)= P(X=0)+2P(x=1)+2P(x=4)+...+2P(X=n)=1?$ $X \in (0, 1,...,n^2)$

Answer (score 1):

a)

Observe that $X^2$ takes values in $\{k^2\mid k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}\}$.

That tells us that it is enough to give an expression for $P(X^2=k^2)$ where $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$.

This leads to $P(X^2=k^2)=P(X=k)=\cdots$

b)

Observe that $X^2$ takes values in $\{k^2\mid k\in\{-n,-n+1,\dots-1,0,1,\dots,n-1,n\}\}$.

That tells us that it is enough to give an expression for $P(X^2=k^2)$ where $k\in\{-n,-n+1,\dots-1,0,1,\dots,n-1,n\}\}$.

This leads to $P(X^2=k^2)=P(X=-k\text{ or }X=k)=\cdots $

Answer (score 0):

$P(X^2=y)=P(X=\sqrt y$  $\bigcup$ $X=-\sqrt y)=P(X=\sqrt y) + P( X=-\sqrt y)$

Since you know the distribution of $X$, can you now complete the problem?